# spring-data JpaRepository save() method side effect

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I've noticed a very strange behavior with the `save(T entity)` in the spring-data JpaRepository.

I have the entity `Foo foo` and I'm trying to save it with repository `fooRepository.save(foo)`.
My issue is, the after saving, the instance of `foo` that I'm passing to the `save()` method is changed. I do not expect this, and I'm very strange that I can't find any issue related to it.

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can try to understand your observations by first checking the [Javadoc for CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#save-S-):

> Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations **as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.**

One possible explanation here is that when you saved, some other thread or process had also modified the underlying entity.  Here is what the `save()` method actually does:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);   // <-- this is your use case
    }
}
```

It will call `em.merge()`, which will return with whatever new underlying changes have been made to the record/entity in the database.  So, you should check to see what else might be updating this entity in the background.

Comment: Thanks, what confuses is the word `might` in the JavaDoc. I find it weird that the behavior can be different

Comment: @SergiiBishyr The language perhaps is ambiguous.  Stating that `save()` may have changed the underlying entity does not necessarily mean that your code is what is doing the changing.

Comment: What also confuses me, is the phrase `Use the returned instance`. However, in my case, both the returned instance and the one that I pass to the method are equals after the method finish executing

Comment: Well in that case you should check the contract of `equals()` which has been defined for the entity.  If, for example, equals is just checking the primary key, then yes, the two objects might be "equal."

Comment: The contract is ok, I can really see that bot the instance that I pass to the method and the returned one are the same after the `save()` method

Comment: @SergiiBishyr Your comment above seems to contradict the problem statement in your original question.  If there really be no change before and after `save()`, then your original problem does not exist.

Comment: It's not the same. The same are the entity instance returned from the `save()` method and the one that I pass to the `save()` method. But they `equals` only after the `save` method is executed, since it mutates the state if the parameter.